# Validation in case of multiple objects serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization, formset, django-rest-viewsets

My data input is in the form of list of 'n' number of dicts

```
"contact_person":[
               {
                   "contactperson_salutation[0]":"sddd",
                   "contactperson_first_name[0]":"santoorr",
                   "contactperson_last_name[0]":"",
                   "contactperson_email[0]":"gfgh",
                   "contactperson_mobile_number[0]":"",
                   "contactperson_work_phone_number[0]":"jio"
               },
               {
                   "contactperson_salutation[1]":"dfsf",
                   "contactperson_first_name[1]":"lux",
                   "contactperson_last_name[1]":"",
                   "contactperson_email[1]":"",
                   "contactperson_mobile_number[1]":"",
                   "contactperson_work_phone_number[1]":"9048"
               }, .............]
```

My model is like this:

```
class ContactPerson(models.Model):

   client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   contactperson_salutation = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=SALUTATIONS)
   contactperson_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   contactperson_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
   contactperson_email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
   contactperson_mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
   contactperson_work_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

How to write serializer when the fields names are changing for every dict in the input list..

And if errors occurs the Error Response should be in this format:

```
            [
                {
                    "contactperson_email[0]":"Invalid Email",
                    "contactperson_mobile_number[0]":"Invalid mobile phone",
                    "contactperson_work_phone_number[0]":"Invalid workphone number"
                },
                {
                    "contactperson_mobile_number[1]":"Invalid mobile phone",
                    "contactperson_work_phone_number[1]":"Invalid workphone number"
                }
             ]
```

Comment: I think the data you're receiving from the frontend needs to be in the correct `JSON` format. maybe try using `JSON. stringify()`.

Comment: Could u specify how should be the format

Comment: `contactperson_salutation` is possibly an `array` on the frontend and it needs to be sent in the right format on the backend.

Comment: contact_person like  a array of objects which contains contactperson_salutation

Answer (score 0):

You would probably benefit from parsing the `"contactperson_salutation[0]"`-like strings to build a `list` `contactperson_salutation` with all the ocurrences.

Same thing for each of the other fields.

Comment: could u explain in code please ? and  how will the error response be also shown in that case..

Answer (score 0):

try overwriting the `to_internal_value` method of the Serializer to achieve this. 
But the error would still be not in the format you require. 
The error message will contain your model keys, not the keys which are suffixed with `[x]`.

```
class ContactPersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ContactPerson
        fields = [
        "contactperson_salutation",
        "contactperson_first_name",
        "contactperson_last_name",
        "contactperson_email",
        "contactperson_mobile_number",
        "contactperson_work_phone_number",
    ]

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if hasattr(data, "_mutable"):
            data._mutable = True

        data = {key[:-3]: value for key, value in data.items()}

        if hasattr(data, "_mutable"):
            data._mutable = False

        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```